# Solution for this linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$P$ is a rotation matrix with $\theta=30$ and $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ and let $Q=PAP^{T}$ where $P^{T}$ is P transpose then what is $P^T(Q^{2005})P$ . I solved for $Q$ but it doesnt give a good matrix any trick hint or ideas are welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but i exactly dont knowathjax for matrices

Comment: Did you try to diagonalize $Q$?

Comment: You have to write $Q=BDB^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal.  Then $Q^{2005}=BD^{2005}B^{-1}$.  And it's very easy to raise $D$ to a high power since it is diagonal you just raise the entries to that power.  Whenever you are asked to raise a matrix to a high power then they probably are expecting you to diagonalize it.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to remember that $P$ as a rotation matrix is orthogonal
$$ P^TP = 1 $$ so for $n\geq 2$

$$ (P^TQP)^n = P^TQ(PP^T)QP(P^TQP)^{n-2} = P^TQ^nP$$

Now relate $Q$ to $A$ whose matrix powers are computable fairly straightforward, because $A$ can be diagonalized.

Raising a diagonalizable matrix to some power works essentially the same way. Say $D$ is diagonal such that

$$ A = S^{-1}DS $$ then $$ A^n = S^{-1}DSS^{-1}DS\cdots = S^{-1}D^nS$$